# What does "it should be for everyone" mean?

Tags: meaning

> we firmly believe security matters most and **it should be for everyone**. (https://www.digitaltrends.com/home/reolink-argus-2/)

Does "it should be for everyone" means "Security should be for everyone"?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: I think it's poorly worded. Looking at the article it seems to suggest that they want security products to be accessible for everyone (ie not just security experts), as security affects everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means that the security should be available for everyone.